# Category drop-down with auto submit

Tags: categories, javascript

I'm using this bit of code to display my categories as a dropdown and make it be autosubmit:

```
<form>
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
{exp:channel:categories channel="news"}
<option><a href="{path=news/list}">{category_name}</a> </option>
 {/exp:channel:categories}
</select>
</form>
```

The issue is that the JavaScript seems to be attaching a question mark at the end of the URL, and so the category URLs break. Is there any way around this? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pure javascript, not about EECMS.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery:

```
$('.jump-menu').change(function() {
    location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

Just add a class of `.jump-menu` to your select, or adjust your jQuery selector accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select name="selcat" id="selcat" onchange="location=document.catmenu.selcat.options[document.catmenu.selcat.selectedIndex].value;">
    {exp:channel:categories channel="news"}
    <option><a href="{path=news/list}">{category_name}</a> </option>
     {/exp:channel:categories}
    </select>
```